# Can not create a file in bootscript.sh at boot

Tags: boot, file

I am on a Pi Zero 2W running headless with SSH.

I modified crontab to run `bootscript.sh` on reboot and `bootscript.sh` runs on startup successfully except for the writes to a file.  However, if I run `bootscript.sh` the command line

```
./bootscript.sh
```

The `dragon.log` is written as planned.

See the code below...

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

LOG_FILE=~/dragon.log
THE_DATE="$(date +"%D %T")"
echo "${THE_DATE} begin log" >> $LOG_FILE

echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness
echo "ACT LED is off" >> $LOG_FILE
```

What am I missing?

Comment: **Who's** crontab did you use? Are you aware of what the tilde in `~/dragon.log` means?

Comment: tilda = home directory

Comment: Right, so again: **Who's** crontab did you use?

Comment: "I modified crontab" HOW? What EXACTLY did you type? What does `crontab -l` show?

Answer (score 0):

Not the question you asked but you use
`echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness` - presumably to turn the ACT LED off.

It is preferable to control with Device Tree.

Including `dtparam=act_led_trigger=none` in `config.txt` should turn it off.
(I use `dtparam=act_led_trigger=heartbeat` to give heartbeat as an indicator the Pi is running as I consider the default useless.)

Answer (score 0):

###### `What am I missing?`

A couple of things I think:

1. Writing to `sysfs` - `/sys/class/leds/led0/brightness` in this case - should not be done with `sudo`. Instead, you should use the `root crontab` to run your script:

```bash
$ sudo crontab
```

Once the root crontab is opened for editing, create your `cron` job as follows:

```
@reboot sleep 5; /home/pi/bootscript.sh >> /home/pi/dragon.log 2>&1
```

2. In your script, make this change:

> FROM: LOG_FILE=~/dragon.log
> TO: LOG_FILE=/home/pi/dragon.log

In summary:

- `sudo` in your `user crontab` works in RPi, but it will not work in general, so don't adopt bad habits.
- The `root crontab` should be used to schedule jobs that require `root` privileges.
- Jobs that run under `cron` (user or root) are run in an environment   different from the environment in your interactive/login shell. You can see this difference clearly if you ask the system to tell you:

  1. From your user's shell command line:  `$ printenv`
  2. To get this from a `crontab`:

  ```
  0 * * * * /usr/bin/printenv > /home/pi/cronenvironment_root.txt 2>&1 

  # or in a user crontab"

  0 * * * * /usr/bin/printenv > /home/pi/cronenvironment_user.txt 2>&1
  ```

Compare the outputs of 1. and 2. above, and you'll find there are substantial differences. Pay particular attention to the env variable `PATH`. This difference explains why your `cron` jobs may need to use full paths.

---

###### One other point:

The commands required to extinguish the `PWR` and `ACT` vary from version to version, and seem to be continuously in a state of flux. If you find that something that ***used to work*** no longer works, you may have to [go digging to learn why](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/1742). I try to stay [current in this recipe](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/LEDControlForRPi.md), but as a surly outsider I make no guarantees :)